# scraping html text using python

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

how can i get the word Rodger Federer only from the html below

```
<div class="profile-heading--desktop"><h1><span class="profile-heading__rank">#1 </span>Roger Federer</h1><div class="profile-subheading">Athlete, Tennis</div></div>
```

am using this code

```
name = soup.find(class_ = 'profile-heading__rank').get_text()
```

and am getting
#1
​

Comment: If the code you're working in is Python, it would be worth adding that (and the appropriate version) as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to get the text *next to* the `<h1>`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="profile-heading--desktop">
    <h1>
        <span class="profile-heading__rank">#1 </span>
        Roger Federer
    </h1>
    <div class="profile-subheading">
        Athlete, Tennis
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
name = soup.find(class_='profile-heading__rank').next_sibling

print(name)  # -->  Roger Federer
```

Answer (score 0):

A other way is to use `.find(text=True, recursive=False)` after finding `h1`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="profile-heading--desktop"><h1><span class="profile-heading__rank">#1 </span>Roger Federer</h1><div class="profile-subheading">Athlete, Tennis</div></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('h1').find(text=True, recursive=False))
```

Output:

`Roger Federer`